# using multiple aggregate operators in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose query that is using the $or aggregator to see if a name passed in a pram matches a first or last name.

The query is case sensitive and I want to use the $toLower aggregator to make it a insensitive case query.

But I can't seem to figure out how to include the $toLower operator.

Here is my code:

```
export let findByFirstOrLastName = (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    User.find({$or: [
        {firstName: req.params.name},
        {lastName: req.params.name}
    ]}).exec((err, user) => {
        if(err) {
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            res.send(user);
        }
    })
}
```

I've tried it just before the $or and also on each of the fields.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply project first the data with `$toLower` and then `$match`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      firstName: { $toLower: "$firstName" },
      lastName: { $toLower: "$lastName" }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        { firstName: req.params.name },
        { lastName: req.params.name }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

You can see it [working here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ma9xH91ARBV)

With all being said you probably should take a look at the [`$text`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/index.html) search if you are going to match agains the strings. And [`$regex`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/index.html) since they usually go hand in hand. This current way you are doing it would not match `joh` in `john` etc.